# PHP startup error using CodeIgniter 3

Tags: codeigniter-3, php-7

I am getting tbe following error intermittently on my website

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Core Warning

Message: PHP Startup: Invalid library (appears to be a Zend Extension, try loading using zend_extension=opcache.so from php.ini)

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0

Backtrace:
```

I  am using LAMP with PHP7 and the CodeIgniter installation is standard. The error has no file nor line to investigate, but my host ensures me that the server is correctly configured.

What could be causing this? I cannot even find a reference to opcache in the CodeIgniter 3 source code. (application files are very basic MVC brochureware stuff, so it's nothing the app has added)

Comment: Have you tried the zend_extension=opcache.so from php.ini suggestion?

Comment: I don't have access to php.ini as it's a shared server, but the host say its all configured properly.